# Couldn't scroll to full content inside coordinator layout?

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I cannot scroll to full content when placing a scrollview layout inside co-ordinator layout, it is not scrolling properly. Scroll was not smooth, even I won't scroll sometimes even if it scroll my toolbar gone missing.

I don't know where am making mistake. I have read many Stack Overflow question regarding this but nothing has solved my problem. Let me post my code:

This is my coordinator layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
        <View
            android:id="@+id/appbar_bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/activity_visit_updation"
       />



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/a"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#e3e3e3"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20sp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".Activities.VisitUpdation">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/root1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="#fff">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/visittext"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/VisitUpdate"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textColor="@color/SForange"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

            </LinearLayout>


            <View
                android:id="@+id/view1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="3dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/title"
                android:background="@color/SForange"
                android:gravity="center" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/checkin_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/view1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/Checkin" />


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/checkin"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/checkin_text"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:cursorVisible="true"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:paddingLeft="12dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/checkinview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/checkin"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:background="#e3e3e3"
                android:gravity="center" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/checkout_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/checkinview"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/Checkout" />


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/checkout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/checkout_text"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:cursorVisible="true"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:paddingLeft="12dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                android:textSize="14sp" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btn_checkout"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/checkout"
                android:layout_below="@+id/checkout_text"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_stop_black_24dp" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/checkoutview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/checkout"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:background="#e3e3e3"
                android:gravity="center" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/findingatsite_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/checkoutview"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/findingatsite" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/findingatsite"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/findingatsite_text"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:cursorVisible="true"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:paddingLeft="12dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/findingatsite"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:background="#e3e3e3"
                android:gravity="center" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/actiontaken_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/view3"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/ActionTaken" />


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/actiontaken"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/actiontaken_text"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:cursorVisible="true"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:paddingLeft="12dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/actiontakenview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/actiontaken"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:background="#e3e3e3"
                android:gravity="center" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/status_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/actiontakenview"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/status" />


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/status"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/status_text"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:cursorVisible="true"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_down_black_24dp"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:paddingLeft="12dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/statusview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/status"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:background="#e3e3e3"
                android:gravity="center" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/pending_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/statusview"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/pending_status" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/pending_status"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/pending_text"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:cursorVisible="true"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_down_black_24dp"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:paddingLeft="12dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/pendingtextview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/pending_status"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:background="#e3e3e3"
                android:gravity="center" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nextvisitdate_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/pendingtextview"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/nextvisitdate" />


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/nextvisitdate"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/nextvisitdate_text"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:cursorVisible="true"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:paddingLeft="12dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/nextvisitdateview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/nextvisitdate"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:background="#e3e3e3"
                android:gravity="center" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cutoffdate_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/nextvisitdateview"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/cutoffdate" />


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/cutoffdate"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/cutoffdate_text"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:cursorVisible="true"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:paddingLeft="12dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/cutoffdateview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/cutoffdate"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:background="#e3e3e3"
                android:gravity="center" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/remarks_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/cutoffdateview"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/remarks" />


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/remarks"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/remarks_text"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:paddingLeft="12dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/remarksview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/remarks"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:background="#e3e3e3"
                android:gravity="center" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/atta_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/remarksview"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/attachment" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/attachment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/atta_text"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:cursorVisible="true"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:paddingLeft="12dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/attach"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/attachment"
                android:layout_below="@+id/atta_text"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_attachment" />


        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_spare_request"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/root1"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
           android:background="#fff">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/spare_text"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/Spare"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textColor="@color/SForange"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_spare"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#ffcc80"
                    android:minHeight="0dp"
                    android:minWidth="0dp"
                    android:text="+"
                    android:textColor="#fff" />

            </LinearLayout>


            <View
                android:id="@+id/view2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="3dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/header"
                android:background="@color/SForange"
                android:gravity="center" />
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/spare_recyclerview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/view2" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/empty_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/view2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingBottom="75dp"
                android:text="No Data Available"
                android:visibility="visible" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I have tried windowssoftinputmethod to adjustresize and fitwindows screen to true but nothing has happened.

Comment: try by using android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView instade of ScrollView & move android:fitsSystemWindows="true" to coordinatorLayout from scrollview

Comment: still not working

Comment: :D i think you have computation-intensive task in your activity or thread so UI doesn't work properly and laggy. post your code. if that's not the case, notify me.